# Finding special vectors generated by a matrix

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, matrices, algorithms, discrete-geometry, lattices

Let $G\in \Bbb Z^{n\times n}$ be a unimodular matrix.

Are there any efficient algorithms to find the maximum norm of a vector $v$ that satisfies $\langle\Delta(v),v\rangle=0$ over all vectors $v\in xG$ within a ball of radius $r$ at the origin, where $x\in \Bbb Z^{n}$ and $\Delta\in \Bbb Z^{n\times n}$ is another unimodular matrix?

$\Delta$ is a tensor product of matrices of the form:
$$ \begin{matrix}
-1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
 0 & a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 0 & a_{n1} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix} $$
where the $a_{ii}$s form a self-adjoint circulant matrix.

Comment: Is $\Delta$ symmetric?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Introduced $\Delta$.